# Good window management grid keyboard shortcuts on keyboards without a numeric keypad

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager

I like to use [Winsplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) to position open windows in a specific place on my screen in a grid-like fashion.  One of the things I like about Winsplit Revolution is that the default keyboard shortcuts use the physical layout of the numeric keypad as a mnemonic for where each key positions a window (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> positions window in top left hand corner because <kbd>7</kbd> is in top left hand corner and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> positions window in bottom right hand corner because <kbd>3</kbd> is in bottom right hand corner).

I am looking to get a laptop (Macbook Pro) whose keyboard does not feature a numeric keypad.  Can anyone suggest a set of keyboard shortcuts on such a machine that provides a similar mnemonic to aid in remembering what each shortcut does, rather than a simple arbitrary assignment of shortcuts?  To be clear, I am not interested in specific window management software, just suggestions for keyboard shortcuts that are easy to remember.